# android build path conflict?

Tags: android, android-ndk

i try to embed the java file for ebay sharing with supported jar files, and i also have the jar file of ksoap2 for xml parsing.

The following error is shown in package,i don`t know how to recover it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After implementing JRE system library the problem is resolved.